# Factoring $z^4+64=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, factoring

I've been asked to factor $z^4+64=0$ in the structure 
$(z^2+Az+B)(z^2+Cz+D)=0$, 
where $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are real numbers. I've found the four roots of the equation, but I don't know how to find those structures. Should I try combining the roots until I get that structure or is there any less 'artificial' method? I thought about $(a+b)(a+b)=(a^2+2ab+b^2)$, but there are some i I can't avoid.
Thank you.

Comment: How about separating those four roots into complex conjugate pairs?

Comment: Yes, but there were still i around and didn't manage to work them out. I think the most intuitive way to do it is the one @User289143 has mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
(z^2+Az+B)(z^2+Cz+D)=z^4+(A+C)z^3+(AC+B+D)z^2+(AD+BC)z+BD
$$
so we get a system of equations in $A,B,C,D$
$$
A+C=0 \\
AC+B+D=0 \\
AD+BC=0 \\
BD=64
$$
If you solve it, you get $A=4,C=-4,B=D=8$ and thus $z^4+64=(z^2+4z+8)(z^2-4z+8)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$z^4+64=z^4+16z^2+64-16z^2=(z^2+8)^2-(4z)^2=(z^2+4z+8)(z^2-4z+8)$$